Deleting an object from a double (deep) nested array in Spring Boot via MongoDB
I have a set of data that looks like this:
// Contained in a document named "Account"
{
  "_id": abc-123,
  "name": "MY-ACCOUNT",
  "primary_contact_email": "test@test.com",
  "projects": [
    {
      "projectId": xyz-456,
      "name": "Test Project",
      "description": "Description of project",
      "credentials": [
        {
          "credentialId": efg-789,
          "name": "Test Credential 1"
        },
        {
          "credentialId": dbc-987,
          "name": "Test Credential 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I would like to be able to delete a credential based on the credentialId. I've tried a few pieces of Java code to accomplish this, most recently this:
Query q = new Query();
q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(accountId).and("projects.projectId").is(projectId));
Update u = new Update().pull("projects.$.credentials", Query.query(Criteria.where("credentialId").is(credentialId)));
var result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(q, u, Account.class);
log.info(result.toString());

I feel like this is kind of close but am not sure why it's not pulling/deleting the specific credential. I'm not receiving any errors with the above code, the result just states AcknowledgedUpdateResult{matchedCount=0, modifiedCount=0, upsertedId=null}.
This is my first time using MongoDB so I think the schema is correct, but am willing to change if necessary to accomplish this along with the other CRUD operations.
I know I could accomplish this is Java code using loops and indexes, but I thought that would defeat the purpose of Mongos performance.
I'm using the Spring Boot starter: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb which pulls in the latest 5.1 driver.

To update a nested array field you can use the filtered positional operator which uses arrayFilters to identify a specific array element to be updated / deleted.

I don't think you can use $pull here. You can use a nested sub-array condition, it still pulls the full item from the parent array, not just the sub-array element. (see notes below)
The other issue is that you want to do check for projectId on the parent of the sub-array element, and not just fields within the sub-array. At least, this doesn't work for $pull. (see notes below)
This will need an update-pipeline to filter in/out based on the element projectId and sub-element credentialId:
$map all projects and filter the credentials array for those sub-elems which are not the id you want to update. This will only remove credentials with credentialId="dbc-987" under projectId="xyz-456". I've add some more elements and sub-elements to demonstrate what will/won't get filtered out.
db.collection.update({ _id: "abc-123" },
[
  {
    $set: {
      projects: {
        $map: {
          input: "$projects",
          as: "proj",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$proj",
              {
                credentials: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$proj.credentials",
                    as: "cred",
                    cond: {
                      $or: [
                        { $ne: ["$$proj.projectId", "xyz-456"] },
                        { $ne: ["$$cred.credentialId", "dbc-987"] }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
Notes:

Wrt pulling the full item from the array, and not just the sub-element in the sub-array: Here are two examples showing that, maybe I'm missing something: Playground One; Playground Two.

The arrayFilters approach doesn't work at all: fail one, fail two.

Using an example directly from the docs for arrayFilters - Update Nested Arrays in Conjunction with $[] - but modified to $pull instead: with one filter; with two filters



Thank you for your response! I took your code snippet and used it in the mongo playground with my data and it looks like it works playground. Any chance you know how to accomplish this in Spring? I have access to MongoRepository and MongoTemplate.
Edit: Also, thank you for your explanations.

@WillEstes Unfortunately, I don't know Java/Spring. But if you can use each of the keywords in the pipeline steps to translate to equivalent Java/Spring, then it should be fine. Optionally, paste that into the "Aggregation" tab of Mongo Compass and use 'export to language' --> Java.
